# How to group up all Retrofit networking code in a separate class and communicate response without tight coupling or memory leaks? MVVM

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm

I have a class that deals with all Networking operations using Retrofit as shown below:

```
public class Networking{

public static void getCustomers(final PreviewCustomersViewModel previewCustomersViewModel) {
        final Call<List<Customer>> getCustomersCall = service.getCustomers();

        getCustomersCall.enqueue(new Callback<List<Customer>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<List<Customer>> call, @NonNull Response<List<Customer>> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    previewCustomersViewModel.selectedDistCustomers = response.body();
                    previewCustomersViewModel.isCustomerListRetrieved.setValue(true);
                    //Send Broadcast Msg
                } else {
                    previewCustomersViewModel.isCustomerListRetrieved.setValue(false);
                   //Send Broadcast Msg
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<List<Customer>> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                  previewCustomersViewModel.isCustomerListRetrieved.setValue(false);
                  //Send Broadcast Msg
            }
        });
    }
}
```

As you can see, I pass a reference of a ViewModel object to the method that does the networking call, and after receiving the response I communicate that on a Livedata object in that ViewModel. (Or using a broadcast message)

But, I think this can be a source of memory leaks for the ViewModel object that I pass around if the user moves from one activity to another.

Using a broadcast message would not require me to pass the ViewModel object, but is it a good approach?

Is there a better way to achieve this? Using RxJava maybe? Or should I just keep the Retrofit code inside the ViewModel? I want to implement the cleanest solution.

Comment: The onCleared method in the viewmodel of the activity you have passed will be activated..In the case of OnDestroy, because Cleared is running, the corresponding scope will prevent memory leakage.

Comment: @kzncrda But then, trying to access a property of the viewmodel in the Retrofit callback would produce an error, right?

Comment: I do not recommend using retrofit processes in ViewModel.

Comment: @kzncrda So, is my approach good?

Comment: There is a static method attached to the ViewModel. My suggestion. Starting empowerment from a single center. Managing your call operations in the information pool.